# Communication on Base class's collection's generic type

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Please help me solve the following C++ design Questions

```
Class Office 
{
    std::list<Employees *> m_Employees; 
    string m_Address;

    void AddEmployee(Employees *employee);
    string GetAddress();    
}
Class SalesOffice : public Office
{
    int  m_TotalEmployees_SalesPerYear;
    int GetSalesPerYear();  
}
Class FinanceOffice : public Office
{
    int m_TotalEmployees_ProfitPerYear;
    int GetProfitPerYear(); 
}
Class BookKeepingOffice : public Office
{
    int m_TotalEmployees_RecordsPerYear;
    int GetRecordsPerYear();    
}


Class Employees
{
    int id; 
    int GetID();
}
Class SalesEmployees : public Employees
{
    int m_SalesPerYear;
    int GetEmployeeSalesPerYear();  
}
Class FinanceEmployees : public Employees
{
    int m_ProfitPerYear;
    int GetEmployeeProfitPerYear(); 
}
Class BookKeepingEmployees : public Employees
{
    int m_RecordsPerYear;
    int GetEmployeeRecordsPerYear();    
}
```

Class Office has a list of Class Employees. This composite relation cannot be changed.
Apparently, Any type of Office only knows Employees. 
Question: How does SalesOffice's GetSalesPerYear can access GetEmployeeSalesPerYear()
Note: I do not want to typecast employees in each office.
Any suggesstion on design and design patterns?

Comment: This code is fundamentally flawed.  You cannot use a `list<Employees>` to store instances of `SalesEmployees`, etc., as that will invoke the [*slicing problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: yogesh veeraraghavan, why do you not select an answer for any of your question? You also got useful replies. If you find problems with them, let the authors know that, or select their answers.

Answer (score 0):

`int GetEmployeeSalesPerYear();` should be defined as virtual method of `Employee`, returning 0 and  `SalesEmployees` should reimplement it.

Comment: My Bad, It is a list of pointer actually. and yes you are right that i have to make that pure virtual int GetEmployeeSalesPerYear(); But that would bloat Employees class which is not desirable as it will lead to lot of dummy implementation on all Employeess that is not relevant. Instead i want a way of passing the request and each employee should take care of it.

Comment: @yogeshveeraraghavan I just edited, it doesn't need to be pure and can implement default value od 0.